# Copy constructor inheritance dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have the following class where I need to make a copy constructor which copies a dynamically allocate array. However, in the code below it uses the constructor of C and not the copy constructor. How do I fix this?

```
    #ifndef B_HH
    #define B_HH

    #include <iostream>

    #include "C.hh"

    class B {
    public:

      B() { std::cout << "Constructor B" << this << std::endl ;  array = new C[len];}
      B(const B& other): array(other.array) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor B" << this << std::endl ; 
       array = new C[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
           array[i] = other.array[i];
       } 

      }
      ~B() { std::cout << "Destructor B" << this << std::endl ; delete[] array;}

    private:


       C *array;
       static const int len = 12;

    } ;

    #endif
```

And my class C looks like this:

```
    #ifndef C_HH
    #define C_HH

    #include <iostream>

    class C {
    public:

      C() { std::cout << "Constructor C" << this << std::endl ; }
      C(const C&) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor C" << this << std::endl ; }
      ~C() { std::cout << "Destructor C" << this << std::endl ; }

    private:

    } ;

    #endif
```

Comment: constructor is called at `new C[len]` followed by assignment, no copy.

Comment: How would I change this? I am just staring to learn c++.

Comment: You do not need to change anything for this code. (or you should use `vector`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will call `len` number of default `C` constructors

```
array = new C[len];
```

Then this line should actually call the *copy assignment* operator

```
array[i] = other.array[i];
```

Add this line to `C` and you will see this is a copy assignment

```
C& operator=(const C&)
{
    std::cout << "Copy Assignment Operator C" << this << std::endl;
    /* do actual copying here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this?

Well, you don't need to.  In this case that is the proper behavior.  Since you need to make a deep copy when you do

```
array = new C[len];
```

In `B`'s copy constructor you default construct `len` number of `C`'s in the memory location `new` gives you.  You then call copy assignment operator of `C` `len` times in

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    array[i] = other.array[i];
}
```